# How to find all nodes and their links to other nodes by traversing them in both directions (fathers and children)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, recursion

I have a client application consuming data from an external API based on a configuration during startup.

Since calculating the necessary data is not easy for me, I tried to fake the implementation and calculate it locally for now.

There are many *WorkItems* linked to each other and the configuration only knows about the relations to consider.

---

**Some explanations:**

*Workitem*

A workitem has a unique id and a type

e.g.

```
{
    id: 1,
    type: "person"
}
```

so you know that *Workitem 1 is of type person*

*Linkrole*

A linkrole is a composite key of three keys

- The parrent workitem type
- The child workitem type
- The name of the role

e.g.

```
{
    parentWorkItemType: "person",
    childWorkItemType: "house",
    name: "owns",
}
```

which represents *Person owns House*

*Links*

The backend knows about the relations, a link between workitems might look like

```
{
    /* each link is unique */
    linkRole: {
        parentWorkItemType: "person",
        childWorkItemType: "house",
        name: "owns",
    },
    parentId: 1,
    childId: 2
}
```

so you know that *Person 1 owns House 2*

---

**Fake prerequisites:**

*Fake backend*

I created some fake data for my calculations. The file *backend.js* represents the backend / database

```
// backend.js

export const workItems = [{
    id: 1,
    type: "car"
}, {
    id: 2,
    type: "car"
}, {
    id: 3,
    type: "bird"
}, {
    id: 4,
    type: "bird"
}, {
    id: 5,
    type: "bird"
}, {
    id: 6,
    type: "invalid"
}, {
    id: 7,
    type: "house"
}, {
    id: 8,
    type: "house"
}, {
    id: 9,
    type: "house",
}, {
    id: 10,
    type: "person",
}];

export const workItemLinks = [{
    linkRole: {
        parentWorkItemType: "car",
        childWorkItemType: "bird",
        name: "isChildOf",
    },
    parentId: 1,
    childId: 3
}, {
    linkRole: {
        parentWorkItemType: "car",
        childWorkItemType: "bird",
        name: "isChildOf",
    },
    parentId: 1,
    childId: 4
}, {
    linkRole: {
        parentWorkItemType: "bird",
        childWorkItemType: "house",
        name: "with",
    },
    parentId: 3,
    childId: 7
}, {
    linkRole: {
        parentWorkItemType: "bird",
        childWorkItemType: "house",
        name: "with",
    },
    parentId: 3,
    childId: 8
}, {
    linkRole: {
        parentWorkItemType: "person",
        childWorkItemType: "car",
        name: "owns",
    },
    parentId: 10,
    childId: 1
}, {
    linkRole: {
        parentWorkItemType: "car",
        childWorkItemType: "car",
        name: "references",
    },
    parentId: 1,
    childId: 2
}];
```

*Fake API*

I created some methods inside the file *api.js* to fake an API asking the backend for data.

*Important sidenote:* These methods just help me to find the data I need. I can add more "helpers" if needed (In the real world I can ask to add more API endpoints) so everything can be queried. Please feel free to modify the "Fake API".

```
// api.js

import { workItems, workItemLinks } from "./backend.js";

export function getWorkItemsByType(workItemType) {
    return workItems.filter(workItem => workItem.type === workItemType);
}

export function getWorkItemsByIds(workItemIds) {
    return workItems.filter(workItem => workItemIds.some(workItemId => workItemId === workItem.id));
}

export function getWorkItemLinksByLinkRoleAndLeftSideIds(linkRole, leftSideIds, leftSideIsParentSide) {
    return workItemLinks.filter(workItemLink => {
        
        // Pseudo equality check
        
        if (workItemLink.linkRole.parentWorkItemType === linkRole.parentWorkItemType &&
            workItemLink.linkRole.childWorkItemType === linkRole.childWorkItemType &&
            workItemLink.linkRole.name === linkRole.name) {
            const leftSideIdInLink = leftSideIsParentSide ? workItemLink.parentId : workItemLink.childId;

            // Return this link if it matches with the left side id ( you're looking for the right side id )

            return leftSideIds.some(leftSideId => leftSideId === leftSideIdInLink);
        }
        
        return false;
    });
}
```

*Fake configuration*

I created definitions inside *configuration.js* to start the calculations based on those

```
// configuration.js

export const definitions = [
    {                                           // fetch linked birds from every root car
        linkRole: {                             
            parentWorkItemType: "car",
            childWorkItemType: "bird",
            name: "isChildOf",
        }
    },
    {                                           // !! Root Element !! Fetch work items based on type
        workItemType: "car",
        isRootWorkItem: true
    },
    {                                            // fetch linked houses from every bird ( car - bird - house )
        linkRole: {                            
            parentWorkItemType: "bird",
            childWorkItemType: "house",
            name: "with",
        }
    },
    {                                             // fetch every person from every car ( person - car )
        linkRole: {
            parentWorkItemType: "person",
            childWorkItemType: "car",
            name: "owns",
        }
    },
    {                                          // Self reference, fetch linked cars from every root car
        linkRole: {
            parentWorkItemType: "car",
            childWorkItemType: "car",
            name: "references",
        }
    },
];
```

---

**Problem to solve:**

I am looking for a performant way to fetch every *related* link and workitem from the backend based on the chain of relations starting with each root item.

*Expected output based on the configuration:*

```
export const workItems = [{
    id: 1,
    type: "car"
}, {
    id: 2,
    type: "car"
}, {
    id: 3,
    type: "bird"
}, {
    id: 4,
    type: "bird"
}, /* no car is linked to bird 5, no links for invalid 6 */ {
    id: 7,
    type: "house"
}, {
    id: 8,
    type: "house"
}, /* no bird is linked to house 9 */ {
    id: 10,
    type: "person",
}];

/* based on the configuration every workItemLink from the backend got fetched */
```

---

**My first implementation approach:**

```
import { inspect } from "util";

import { getWorkItemsByType, getWorkItemsByIds, getWorkItemLinksByLinkRoleAndLeftSideIds } from "./api.js";
import { definitions } from "./configuration.js";

// Find the root definition

const { workItemType: rootWorkItemType } = definitions.find(definition => definition.isRootWorkItem);

// Fetch all the root workitems and initialize the store holding unique workitems

const workItems = getWorkItemsByType(rootWorkItemType); // will hold car 1 and car 2

const initialWorkItemIds = workItems.map(workItem => workItem.id);

const workItemIdsToLoad = []; // try to read all missing ids from fetched links and fetch all the workitems at once later on

const workItemLinks = []; // global store for links



const definitionsToTraverse = definitions.filter(definition => definition.linkRole !== undefined); // do not consider the root definition



run(initialWorkItemIds, rootWorkItemType, definitionsToTraverse, workItemIdsToLoad, workItemLinks);




const missingWorkItemIdsToLoad = workItemIdsToLoad.filter(workItemIdToLoad => !rootWorkItemIds.some(rootWorkItemId => rootWorkItemId === workItemIdToLoad)); // filter out all the existing root item ids

const workItemsToAdd = getWorkItemsByIds(missingWorkItemIdsToLoad); // fetch all the missing workitems at once

workItems.push(...workItemsToAdd); // add them to the global store








console.log(inspect({
    workItems,
    workItemLinks
}, false, null, true))









function run(leftSideWorkItemIds, leftSideWorkItemType, definitionsToTraverse, workItemIdsToLoad, workItemLinks) {
    /* 
    
        consider all the defitions from "definitionsToTraverse" directly related to "leftSideWorkItemType"
        remove them from "definitionsToTraverse" to prevent endless loops
        loop backwards so splice won't struggle with the indices

    */

    for (let definitionIndex = definitionsToTraverse.length - 1; definitionIndex >= 0; definitionIndex--) { 
        const currentDefinition = definitionsToTraverse[definitionIndex];
        const { linkRole } = currentDefinition;
        const { parentWorkItemType, childWorkItemType } = linkRole;

        const leftSideWorkItemTypeIsParent = parentWorkItemType === leftSideWorkItemType;
        const leftSideWorkItemTypeIsChild = childWorkItemType === leftSideWorkItemType;

        // Check the direct relation

        if (leftSideWorkItemTypeIsParent || leftSideWorkItemTypeIsChild) {
            // Remove the inspected definition

            definitionsToTraverse.splice(definitionIndex, 1);

            const relatedWorkItemLinks = getWorkItemLinksByLinkRoleAndLeftSideIds(linkRole, leftSideWorkItemIds, leftSideWorkItemTypeIsParent);

            // store all the right side workitem IDs for the next run

            const rightSideWorkItemIds = [];

            for (let relatedWorkItemLinkIndex = 0; relatedWorkItemLinkIndex < relatedWorkItemLinks.length; relatedWorkItemLinkIndex++) {
                const relatedWorkItemLink = relatedWorkItemLinks[relatedWorkItemLinkIndex];
                
                // Process the link if not processed yet
    
                if (!workItemLinks.some(workItemLink => /* !!! pseudo equality check !!! */
                        workItemLink.linkRole.parentWorkItemType === relatedWorkItemLink.linkRole.parentWorkItemType &&
                        workItemLink.linkRole.childWorkItemType === relatedWorkItemLink.linkRole.childWorkItemType &&
                        workItemLink.linkRole.name === relatedWorkItemLink.linkRole.name &&
                        workItemLink.parentId === relatedWorkItemLink.parentId &&
                        workItemLink.childId === relatedWorkItemLink.childId)) {
                    
                    // Push the link to the store
            
                    workItemLinks.push(relatedWorkItemLink);
    
                    // Get the right side id from the link

                    const rightSideWorkItemId = leftSideWorkItemTypeIsParent ? relatedWorkItemLink.childId : relatedWorkItemLink.parentId;
    
                    rightSideWorkItemIds.push(rightSideWorkItemId);

                    // Push the id to the store if it doesn't exist

                    if (!workItemIdsToLoad.some(workItemIdToLoad => workItemIdToLoad === rightSideWorkItemId)) {
                        workItemIdsToLoad.push(rightSideWorkItemId);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Find the opposite workitem type of the current definition

            const rightSideWorkItemType = leftSideWorkItemTypeIsParent ? childWorkItemType : parentWorkItemType;

            // Run again but use this definition as the previous one

            run(rightSideWorkItemIds, rightSideWorkItemType, definitionsToTraverse, workItemIdsToLoad, workItemLinks);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my approach crashes because the backwards loop even runs if `definitionsToTraverse` is empty. And I'm mutating the arrays from the parameters directly, I think I shouldn't do that.

So any help would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: There's a lot here, and I feel as through `linkRole` is entirely irrelevant to the question as asked; could it simply be removed?  Do I have this right?  You have (here) a single root type of `car`. and so you want to include both cars, and then you want to include all nodes which have either of those cars as parent or child values in a link, and then include all nodes which have any of those results a a parent or child in a link, and so on recursively, collecting all the results not in a tree but in a simple list.  Is that right?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I think you are right. The "chains" will be `person - car - bird - house` where `car` is the root one and all the relations are based on it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet the `linkRole` in the 'workItemLinks` is not properly normalized data structure, as the `workItemLinks[].parentId` and `.childId` can in turn reference the `workItems[].id` relating to the associated `.type`, which in turn can query `definitions[].linkRole.parentWorkItemType` or `.childWorkItemType`.  In which case, `linkRole` is necessary, but via the `definitions`.  In short, the `workItems`, `workItemLinks`, and `definitions` are not properly normalized if treating them as server side data tables...  (That being said, also see my next comment...)

Comment: @medsmh suggest within `definitions` to identify a root as just another linked role, but with a parent of null, and name of 'root'.  Also, there is then no need for the attribute of `linkRole`, but rather an array of objects only containing attributes of `parentWorkItemType`, `childWorkItemType`, and `name`.  Eg, `{parentWorkItemType:null, childWorkItemType:"car", name:"root"}`, `{parentWorkItemType:"car", childWorkItemType:"bird", name:"isChildOf"}`.

Comment: Very thorough, but not minimal.  You could save potential answerers a ton of work by trimming it down and making it a runnable snippet.

Comment: @Trentium: I did recognize that this was a denormalized data structure.  But my answer seems to demonstrate that for the purpose of the question, it's entirely irrelevant.  (I skip it altogether but still achieve the desired result.)  I read the question as starting with all element of any root types, find all elements that (recursively) have links to it.  Am I missing an edge case?  Something fundamental?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Added a substantially cleaner version of the code.  I was bothered by the previous implementation.

I may be oversimplifying what you need to do here.  I'm treating this as described in my comment on the question:

> Do I have this right? You have (here) a single root type of car. and so you want to include both cars, and then you want to include all nodes which have either of those cars as parent or child values in a link, and then include all nodes which have any of those results a a parent or child in a link, and so on recursively, collecting all the results not in a tree but in a simple list.

If that's correct, then this seems like a reasonable approach:

```js
const getLinkedIds = (links, ids, toAdd = links 
  .filter (({childId, parentId}) => ids .includes (childId) || ids .includes (parentId))
  .flatMap (({childId, parentId}) => [childId, parentId])
  .filter (id => !ids .includes (id))
) => toAdd .length == 0 ? ids : getLinkedIds (links, ids .concat (toAdd))


const linkedItems = (defs, items, links, 
  rootTypes = defs.filter (({isRootWorkItem = false}) => isRootWorkItem) 
    .map (({workItemType}) => workItemType),
  roots = items .filter (({type}) => rootTypes .includes (type)),
  ids = getLinkedIds (links, roots.flatMap (({id}) => id))
) => items .filter (({id}) => ids .includes (id))


const definitions = [ /* linkTypes deleted */  {workItemType: "car", isRootWorkItem: true}]
const workItems = [{id: 1, type: "car"}, {id: 2, type: "car"}, {id: 3, type: "bird"}, {id: 4, type: "bird"}, {id: 5, type: "bird"}, {id: 6, type: "invalid"}, {id: 7, type: "house"}, {id: 8, type: "house"}, {id: 9, type: "house"}, {id: 10, type: "person"}]
const workItemLinks = [ /* linkTypes deleted */ {parentId: 1, childId: 3}, {parentId: 1, childId: 4}, {parentId: 3, childId: 7}, {parentId: 3, childId: 8}, {parentId: 10, childId: 1}, {parentId: 1, childId: 2}]

console .log (
  linkedItems (definitions, workItems, workItemLinks)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In `linkedItems`, we start with the definitions to collect the root types, then use those to collect all the root elements.  We then call our main function, `getLinkedIds` using links, and the ids of these elements.  Then we filter the items to find those whose ids we chose.

`getLinkedIds` finds all the links that include any of our ids as either parent or child, and adds both parent and child to a list of ids that will be included, and when its done, filters out any that are already in our list.  If this list of ids to add is empty, we're done and return our current list.  Otherwise we recur on the combination of the two lists.  While there may be some inefficiencies here, I think the lists would have to be quite large for them to matter.

I haven't tried to read your code and understand how it differs from this, but if my guess is correct about your requirements, this is relatively simple.

---

### Old Version

<del>This is not my usual coding style, and it bothers me.  I tend to work with direct recursion, and I usually use immutable data structures.  I would love to see an approach that handles this using that style, but I didn't come up with one right away.</del>

**Update**: The comment above applied to this older version of the code.  The newer version seems fine to me.

Here is a description of the original implementation of `getLinkedIds` (the other function has only cosmetic changes):

`getLinkedIds` keeps two lists of ids: those still to process and those we've already processed, repeatedly removing an id from the first list, adding it to the second and then queueing up all the unprocessed `parentId`s for which we have a `childId` link to the current value and then all the unprocessed `childId`s for which we have a `parentId` link to the current value.  When the `toProcess` queue is empty, we return the `processed` one.

And you can expand this snippet to see that version (which I don't recommend:

```js
const getLinkedIds = (links, ids) => {
  const toProcess = [...ids], processed = []
  while (toProcess .length > 0) {
     const id = toProcess .pop ()
     processed .push (id)
     links .filter (({parentId}) => id == parentId) 
       .forEach (({childId}) => {
         if (! processed .includes (childId) && ! toProcess .includes (childId)) {
           toProcess .push (childId)
         }
       })
     links .filter (({childId}) => id == childId) 
       .forEach (({parentId}) => {
         if (! processed .includes (parentId) && ! toProcess .includes (parentId)) {
           toProcess .push (parentId)
         }
       })
  }
  return [...processed] 
}

const linkedItems = (defs, items, links) => {
  const rootTypes = defs .filter (({isRootWorkItem = false}) => isRootWorkItem) 
    .map (({workItemType}) => workItemType)
  const roots = items .filter (({type}) => rootTypes .includes (type))
  const ids = getLinkedIds (links, roots.flatMap (({id}) => id))
  return items .filter (({id}) => ids .includes (id))
}


const definitions = [ /* linkTypes deleted */  {workItemType: "car", isRootWorkItem: true}]
const workItems = [{id: 1, type: "car"}, {id: 2, type: "car"}, {id: 3, type: "bird"}, {id: 4, type: "bird"}, {id: 5, type: "bird"}, {id: 6, type: "invalid"}, {id: 7, type: "house"}, {id: 8, type: "house"}, {id: 9, type: "house"}, {id: 10, type: "person"}]
const workItemLinks = [ /* linkTypes deleted */ {parentId: 1, childId: 3}, {parentId: 1, childId: 4}, {parentId: 3, childId: 7}, {parentId: 3, childId: 8}, {parentId: 10, childId: 1}, {parentId: 1, childId: 2}]

console .log (
  linkedItems (definitions, workItems, workItemLinks)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to provide another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71102756/7764329, I will compare your answer with mine and check for differences :)

Comment: Thanks, @PeterSeliger.  If I really got the requirements right, it's not that complex a problem.  But I'm afraid I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

### General Considerations

Suggest pushing most of the work onto the server, as presumably the `workItems` and `workItemLinks` will be comprised of a large number of records.  If the work of traversing the tree of `workItems` is left to the client making individual API calls, then network latency comes into play...

### Data Structure

Suggest normalizing the data as follows:

- WorkItems - No change.
- WorkItemLinks - Reduce attributes to `parentId` and `childId`, which is essentially a many-to-many entity with the WorkItems entity.
- Definitions - Flatten to `parentWorkItemType`, `childWorkItemType`, and `name`.  Root entries are handled by setting `parentWorkItemType` to null.

*Note also that realistically, the need for `Definitions` is likely not necessary when traversing `WorkItemLinks`, as presumably the entries within the `WorkItemLinks`, when created, were only permitted to be created if the relationship between the `parentId` type and `childId` type conformed to the `Defintions`.  If indeed this is the case, then the proposed code can likely be simplified further...*

### Proposed APIs

The solution below proposes two (2) APIs:

- getDefinitionChain( rootWorkItemType ) - Given a rootWorkItemType (eg, "car"), this API traverses the children and parents of the `Definition` entity, and returns all the related `workItemTypes`.
- getWorkItemChain( rootWorkItemType ) - Initially calls getDefinitionChain to identify the related `workItemTypes`, and then traverses `workItems` starting with the rootWorkItemType.

Again, the concept being that these APIs are server side, reducing the chattiness between the client and server...

```js
const workItems = [{"id":1,"type":"car"},{"id":2,"type":"car"},{"id":3,"type":"bird"},{"id":4,"type":"bird"},{"id":5,"type":"bird"},{"id":6,"type":"invalid"},{"id":7,"type":"house"},{"id":8,"type":"house"},{"id":9,"type":"house"},{"id":10,"type":"person"}];

const workItemLinks = [
  {
    "parentId": 1,
    "childId": 3
  },
  {
    "parentId": 1,
    "childId": 4
  },
  {
    "parentId": 3,
    "childId": 7
  },
  {
    "parentId": 3,
    "childId": 8
  },
  {
    "parentId": 10,
    "childId": 1
  },
  {
    "parentId": 1,
    "childId": 2
  }
];

const definitions = [
  {
    "parentWorkItemType": "car",
    "childWorkItemType": "bird",
    "name": "isChildOf"
  },
  {
    "parentWorkItemType": null,
    "childWorkItemType": "car",
    "name": "root"
  },
  {
    "parentWorkItemType": "bird",
    "childWorkItemType": "house",
    "name": "with"
  },
  {
    "parentWorkItemType": "person",
    "childWorkItemType": "car",
    "name": "owns"
  },
  {
    "parentWorkItemType": "car",
    "childWorkItemType": "car",
    "name": "references"
  }
];


function getDefinitionChain( rootWorkItemType ) {
  
  let alreadyVisitedType = new Set();
  let definitionChain = [];

  function recurse( workItemType ) {

    // Visit the children types...
    let nodeTypeChildList = definitions.filter( def => def.parentWorkItemType === workItemType );
    
    for ( let childType of nodeTypeChildList ) {
      if ( !alreadyVisitedType.has( childType.childWorkItemType ) ) {
        alreadyVisitedType.add( childType.childWorkItemType );
        definitionChain.push( childType.childWorkItemType );
        recurse( childType.childWorkItemType );
      }
    }
    
    // Visit the parent types...
    let nodeTypeParentList = definitions.filter( def => def.childWorkItemType === workItemType );
    
    for ( let parentType of nodeTypeParentList ) {
      // Don't go up the definition chain if parent is null.
      if ( parentType.parentWorkItemType && !alreadyVisitedType.has( parentType.parentWorkItemType ) ) {
        alreadyVisitedType.add( parentType.parentWorkItemType );
        definitionChain.push( parentType.parentWorkItemType );
        recurse( parentType.parentWorkItemType );
      }
    }

  }
  
  recurse( rootWorkItemType )
  if ( !alreadyVisitedType.has( rootWorkItemType ) ) {
    definitionChain.push( rootWorkItemType );
  }
  
  return definitionChain;
  
}


function getWorkItemChain( rootWorkItemType ) {

  // Get the list of allowable definitions...
  let allowableDefinitions = new Set( getDefinitionChain( rootWorkItemType ) );
  
  // Now, traverse the WorkItems tree, ensuring that they are in the WorkItemType list...
  let wim = new Map();
  
  function recurse( workItemCandidates ) {
    
    for ( let workItem of workItemCandidates ) {
      // Is this a workItemType that conforms to our allowable definitions?
      if ( allowableDefinitions.has( workItem.type ) ) {
        // If never having traversed this WorkItem, then let's traverse the children and parents.
        if ( !wim.has( workItem.id ) ) {
          wim.set( workItem.id, workItem );
         
          // Get the list of WorkItems that are children to the workItem.id.
          recurse( workItemLinks.filter( wix => wix.parentId === workItem.id ).map( wil => workItems.find( wif => wif.id === wil.childId )) );
          
          // Get the list of WorkItems that are parents to the workItem.id.
          recurse( workItemLinks.filter( wix => wix.childId === workItem.id ).map( wil => workItems.find( wif => wif.id === wil.parentId )) );
        }
      }
    }
  
  }
  
  // Start with all the workItems that are of type rootWorkItemType.
  recurse( workItems.filter( wi => wi.type === rootWorkItemType ) );
  
  return [...wim.values()];

}

console.log( 'WorkItem Types in Definitions with a root of "car".' );
let definitionChain = getDefinitionChain( 'car' );
console.log( definitionChain );

console.log( 'WorkItems with a root of "car"' );
let workItemChain = getWorkItemChain( 'car' );
console.log( workItemChain );
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to provide another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71102756/7764329, I will compare your answer with mine and check for differences :)